# Is there a way in Blender to replicate what this tool is doing in Maya?

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

Maya has this cool feature that allows you to cut out geo based on its opacity mask. Is there a way to replicate this in Blender using Geo nodes, im very new to Blender and Geo nodes so not too savy on the topic.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)